# How do you properly pass variables in database query as part of an API call?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-cosmosdb, mern

I am working on a MERN stack web app which is hosted on Azure. I am trying to iterate through a list of categories, which I then want to pass into the DB query to get records in each category. After I query the database, I want to be able to access all the records in each category.

Here is how I am calling the API and passing in the category:

```
displayCat() {
    purchaseAPI.getCategories().then(function(response) {
        return response;
    }).then(response => {
        const num = response.length;
        let i=0;
        while (i < num) {
            console.log("i=", i, ": ", response[i]);
            // query db with response[i] as val to pass in
            purchaseAPI.getCategoryPrices(response[i]);
            i++;
        }
    });
}
```

Here's how I'm currently attempting to query the database:

```
    function getCategoryPrices(req, res) {
      return Purchase.collection.find({ category: {req}}).toArray()
      .then(function(categoryData) {
        res.json(categoryData);
      });
    }
```

How do I pass in the response[i] value as the req variable for the database query?

Thanks in advance!